# How to remove surfaces from a layout?

Tags: famo.us

I'm creating a lot of little surfaces that get added to a layout ( int this case a header footer layout), animated, then need to go away.  However, I'm not sure how to remove the surfaces once added?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove nodes from the Render Tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087980/how-to-remove-nodes-from-the-render-tree)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kraig is right about using a RenderController when possible, but I would not suggest it for your case. RenderController works well with large layouts and not so much for small particles and such. RenderController only shows one view at a time.

I have asked about this on the IRC channel and it turns out the way I do it, feels really hacky, but is still the recommended most straight forward approach. The idea is to just redefine the render function to return null.

```
// surface to remove
surface.render = function(){ return null; }
```

That's it!

Just make sure you remove all references in your code as well!

I often do it from an object..

```
delete littleSurfaces['little-surface-key']
```

FWIW The more advanced approach is to actually define a view that controls specifically the surfaces that get rendered. You do this by defining the render function on a custom view that returns what is known as a renderSpec. A renderSpec is a list of hashes that define the surfaces that will be rendered. The example everyone points to is the Flipper class. Take a look at Flippers render function..

https://github.com/Famous/views/blob/master/Flipper.js

Good Luck!

Comment: I have an inputsurface inside a view that is hidden the view is set to null before that happens i set the surface.render = function(){ return null;} and then delete the inputsurface The surface still persists when you do an inspect element. It's display none; so normally i wouldn't care but it's placeholder is being used in an input on another page that has an empty placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You can add/remove surfaces using a **RenderController** object. You can also apply an optional transition when things are shown and hidden.

The DOM may lie to you sometimes, as Famo.us repurposes and recycles DOM Elements for efficiency.

https://famo.us/docs/api/latest/views/RenderController