# Famo.us modifier to effectively do `display: none;`

Tags: javascript, famo.us

Is it possible to create a `Modifier` or `StateModifier` that effectively removes all it's children from the DOM or make them into `display: none;`/ `pointer-events:none`?

I've tried with a Modifier and do `setOpacity(0);` but I want to prevent all the surfaces below from receiving click events too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently not possible to propagate CSS properties from modifiers down to Surfaces.

These are your options:

- Use opacity 0 and translate with Z-index to far far behind, or translate far off screen.
- Use a ContainerSurface - this deepens the DOM, but you can manipulate a containing DIV with display: none.
- Check out the `Fader` modifier. Is has a `cull` option. When true, it removes node from rendering tree.
- Show/hide the node - but this can be a performance penalty. See [discussion here](https://github.com/Famous/core/pull/57) or grab [the show modifier](http://famousco.de/2014/07/addremove-nodes-visibility-modifier/) here.

See also [this Stack Overflow question about removing rendernodes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087980/how-to-remove-nodes-from-the-render-tree)

Comment: Cool, a few good alternatives. Far off screen is best solution for me at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: The cull option seems the most "famo.us" way to do it. Thank you.